# АВЛ-дерево на С++

Tags: c, дерево, c++, алгоритм

Не могли бы пояснить, что такое авл-дерево. В чем его преимущества перед другими деревьями. Если есть возможность, приведите пример кода авл-дерева на С++ или на С.

Answer (score 4):

На РСДН всё разжёвано до мелочей с примерами кода http://www.rsdn.ru/article/alg/bintree/avl.xml